# Python; getting bus error (core dumped); exit code 137 or 135

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following python code which will read a certain column from a list of files and create a new data frames. No matter how much memory I assign for this job (upto 291gb), I always get `Bus error (core dumped) command exit status 137 or sometimes 135`
Any help?

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

# read file paths from input file
input_file_path = sys.argv[1]
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as f:
    file_names = f.read().split()

output_file_path = sys.argv[2]

print("The files are: ", file_names)

# read the third column of the first file as row names
first_file = pd.read_csv(file_names[0], usecols=[2],header=None,sep='\t')
row_names = first_file.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
print("Total number of rows: ", len(row_names))

# read the 11th column of all files and combine into a single data frame
data = [pd.read_csv(file, usecols=[10], header=None, sep="\t") for file in file_names]
data = pd.concat(data, axis=1)

print("The size of data: ", data.shape)
print(data.head())

# set column names
col_names = [os.path.basename(file).replace('.csv', '') for file in file_names]
print("Columns of the data: ", col_names)
data.columns = col_names

# add row names
data['row_names'] = row_names
data = data.drop_duplicates('row_names')
data = data.set_index('row_names')

# clean column names
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace('__original|__permuted|_original|_permuted', '')
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace('__', '_')
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace('_combined', '')
# sort rows by row names
data = data.sort_index()

# write output file
data.to_csv(output_file_path, sep="\t", index=True, header=True)
```